# Error 'Unknown Entity namespace alias' when using 'CompanyNameBundle:User'

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a strange problem with Symfony2. I'm working on a project with 40-50 entities, and with one of them this code doesn't work:

```
$user = $em->getRepository('CompanyUserBundle:User')
    ->findOneBy([
        'username' => $person->getUsername()
    ]);
```

I get the error `Unknown Entity namespace alias 'CompanyUserBundle'.`. The strange thing is that if I change my code to:

```
$user = $em->getRepository('Company\UserBundle\Entity\User')
    ->findOneBy([
        'username' => $person->getUsername()
    ]);
```

It works perfectly... So, what's wrong here? I'm using the `getRepository('Alias:Entity')` construction all around the code, and there isn't any other problem...

I don't know if it's important, but `User` is a child entity from FOSUserBundle `BaseUser` class.

---

**EDIT**

Here is my `User` class (it's located at `src/Company/UserBundle/Entity`):

```
namespace Company\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

   /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

And here a part of my `AppKernel.php`:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            /* ... other, non interesting, bundles... */
            new Company\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new FR3D\LdapBundle\FR3DLdapBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        );
    }
}
```

More information: as @herr said in the comments, using

```
$user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
    ->findOneBy([
        'username' => $person->getUsername()
    ]);
```

works fine... But I don't understand why. Why in this bundle the namespace alias is `UserBundle` instead of `CompanyUserBundle`? I know that this must be a really silly error, but I can't see it...

Comment: Are all the other entities in the same namespace as the `User` entity?

Comment: @xabbuh: No, the `User` entity is the only one in the `UserBundle` namespace.

Comment: Just try using $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User'), I think it's namespace /BundleClassName  may be only UserBundle not CompanyUserBundle.

Comment: @herr: I'll try what you say, but it doesn't made sense... In all the project (and it's really big!) the namespaces are CompanyxxxBundle (\Company\xxxBundle)

Comment: Can you show the code of your `User` class? Did you maybe forget to enable the bundle in the kernel?

Comment: @xabbuh: I've updated the post. There you have all `User`'s code. Also I've added a fragment of `AppKernel.php`.

Comment: @herr: I can't understand why, but you got it. It seems that the namespace alias is `UserBundle` instead of `CompanyUserBundle`... Why?

Comment: At the time of bundle creation it ask for you bundle namespace name. In your case it may have display default name UserBundle instead of CompanyUserBundle and by mistake you have give enter without changing it. You can check in your UserBundle's Bundle class file it will with UserBundle.php instead of CompanyUserBundle.php. :)

Comment: @herr: Exactly! This bundle wasn't created by me (it was from a coworker with less experience in sf2), and he entered the wrong namespace name... Anyway, thank you very much, and please publish an answer so I can mark as correct and vote you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your UserBundle's Bundle class file it will with UserBundle.php instead of CompanyUserBundle.php.

Just try using

```
$em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
```

instead

```
$em->getRepository('CompanyUserBundle:User')
```

I think it's namespace / BundleClassName may be only UserBundle not CompanyUserBundle in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but the reason was different, because Entity's were in different bundle/package.
The problem caused by the mapping misconfiguration. Changing `alias` to the correct one solved the issue

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    # ...
  orm:
    # ...
    mappings:
      App:
        # ...
        prefix: 'Company\UserBundle\Entity'
        alias: CompanyUserBundle # <-- this alias is used when you do CompanyUserBundle:User
```

for more information: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html